# Convert Date to Calendar in Groovy: .setTime() or .toCalendar?

Tags: date, groovy, calendar

I have always converted a Date into a Calendar using the setTime() method

```
Date date = new Date()
def calendar.setTime(date)
```

Recently I found the .toCalendar() method.

```
Date date = new Date()
def calendar = date.toCalendar()
```

What's the difference between them and which should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can [here](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DateGroovyMethods.java) this method does exactly the same:

```
public static Calendar toCalendar(Date self) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(self);
    return cal;
}
```

Comment: I did not see that, thanks. But I don't understand why they made that method.

Comment: This method is just syntactic sugar, it makes easier to use that method.

Comment: @user3811673, it the answer satisfies you, please accept it.